# Extract word after a specific word of HTML using linux command/srcipting

Tags: linux, shell, awk, sed, scripting

i have a file 'tes.html' :

```
<html>
<head><title>Index of /Data/Movies/Hollywood/2016_2017/</title></head>
<body bgcolor="white">
<h1>Index of /Data/Movies/Hollywood/2016_2017/</h1><hr><pre><a href="../">../</a>
<a href="1%20Buck%20%282017%29/">1 Buck (2017)/</a>                                     25-Nov-2019 10:25       -
<a href="1%20Mile%20to%20You%20%282017%29/">1 Mile to You (2017)/</a>                              25-Nov-2019 10:26       -
<a href="1%20Night%20%282016%29/">1 Night (2016)/</a>                                    25-Nov-2019 10:27       -
</pre><hr></body>
</html>
```

I want to get the value after "% 29 / ">" to output.txt and provide a header 'title', example:

```
title
1 Buck (2017)/
1 Mile to You (2017)/
1 Night (2016)/
```

how do I get the output file like the one above using linux commands like awk, sed or others.

I tried this code:

```
awk '{for (I=1;I<NF;I++) if ($I == "%29/">") print $(I+1)}' file
```

Comment: Please do add your efforts(in form of code) in your question, which is highly encouraged on SO, to avoid downvotes, close votes on your question, thank you.

Comment: oke sir, I have added the code that I tried

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With your shown samples, please try following.

```
awk 'BEGIN{print "title"} match($0,/%29\/">[^/]*/){print substr($0,RSTART+6,RLENGTH-5)}'  Input_file
```

***Explanation:*** Adding detailed explanation for above code.

```
awk '                                   ##Starting awk program from here.
BEGIN{print "title"}
match($0,/%29\/">[^/]*/){               ##Using match function to match regex %29\/"> till / here.
  print substr($0,RSTART+6,RLENGTH-5)   ##Printing sub string here.
}
'  Input_file                           ##Mentioning Input_file name here.
```

Comment: thank you for explaining, your code works fine, but what if I want to add a word 'title' on the first line?

Comment: @SardiIrfansyah, sure, fixed it now, please check updated code and let me know, cheers.

Comment: amazing, it worked. do you have a reference in the form of a site or a book for me to learn linux? I am still a beginner and interested in learning linux scripting more deeply

Comment: @SardiIrfansyah, I prefer learning from https://stackoverflow.com/tags/awk/info page. You could start learning awk from here. In case any doubts you have, post a question with your efforts and we will try to guide the, cheers and happy learning.

Answer (score 2):

Also with `awk` you can set `FS` as `'[><]'` and print `$3`:

```
awk -F'[><]' 'BEGIN{ print "title" } /%29/ {print $3}' file
title
1 Buck (2017)/
1 Mile to You (2017)/
1 Night (2016)/
```

or this one using the final of `$2` (condition you need):

```
awk -F'[><]' 'BEGIN{ print "title" } $2 ~ /%29\/"$/ {print $3}' file
title
1 Buck (2017)/
1 Mile to You (2017)/
1 Night (2016)/
```